# Load Github project through jsdelivr CDN

Tags: file-upload, hosting, cdn

Essentially i want to load my github project through a CDN. (jsdelivr or similar)

this is my repositories  https://github.com/shaikatssj/scodec-cdn?files=1

Or i want to host my css js and fonts file and load directly on my webpage.

Comment: what is the exat question here? You already know about jsdelivr.